# What happens after OS X Internet Recovery without erasing disk

Tags: macos, recovery, reinstall

I want to reinstall OS X Yosemite in my MacBook Pro 2015 without erasing the disk. What will I need to reinstall after the process is done? What files are not removed from my hard drive? What files ARE removed from disk?

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't erase, there's little you need to reinstall (assuming you live in your home directory rather than throwing files all over the filesystem root). User files in home directory are preserved. I'm not sure about preferences though, since I've never done a non-erase reinstall of OS X. More info about reinstalling here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18872?locale=en_US, although it doesn't answer your question. Anyway, this question is totally off topic. Go to AskDifferent: https://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I can do a backup of my music and documents, but what about my installed Applications and other settings like my $PATH, java, and .bash_profile. Will they be restored or survive the reinstall?

Comment: I don't know about `/Applications`. Applications shipped with OS X will of course be overwritten; I'm not sure about others, although I think there's no reason they should be deleted. I suggest you back up `/Applications` with Time Machine. Settings (preferences) in `~/Library` shouldn't be removed if you ask me, but of course you should back up, especially `~/Library/Application Support`. I don't know what you mean exactly by `java`. If you mean something you installed to `/usr/local`, then sure, should be there. `.bash_profile` lives in `$HOME` so should definitely be preserved.

Comment: Anyway, any program files (that come straight from installers) should be easy to recover.

Comment: I mean if I install java, homebrew, and other files. Would they be deleted or not?

Comment: I don't know where Java is installed to (I'm not a Java programmer, and I don't see a bom for the Java installer), so not sure. Homebrew should be preserved, as is anything in `/usr/local`, if you ask me. Bottom line: take my advice with a grain of salt. I made it clear in the very beginning that I've never done a non-erase reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @bmike:

"Almost nothing is actually removed. What happens is the installer downloads a fresh and complete set of system files - basically the things that came with the Mac out of the factory minus some iLife apps like Garageband for instance.

The installer doesn't delete any user settings, user files and doesn't even delete apps you installed.

The process is designed to make the system work whether or not you have large or small changes to the system."

[Link](http://%200%20down%20vote%20unaccept%20Almost%20nothing%20is%20actually%20removed.%20What%20happens%20is%20the%20installer%20downloads%20a%20fresh%20and%20complete%20set%20of%20system%20files%20-%20basically%20the%20things%20that%20came%20with%20the%20Mac%20out%20of%20the%20factory%20minus%20some%20iLife%20apps%20like%20Garageband%20for%20instance.%20%20The%20installer%20doesn't%20delete%20any%20user%20settings,%20user%20files%20and%20doesn't%20even%20delete%20apps%20you%20installed.%20%20The%20process%20is%20designed%20to%20make%20the%20system%20work%20whether%20or%20not%20you%20have%20large%20or%20small%20changes%20to%20the%20system.)

Answer (score 0):

Run a backup to save all of your data via Time Machine.

Reinstall OSX.

Restore your data from Time Machine if its not available after reinstall.

Run Disk Utility and have the application search and fix any permissions issues that will almost certainly occur when doing a reinstall with applications pulled from a previous install.

DON'T attempt to do a reinstall without making a backup via Time Machine to an external drive.

Comment: What about my installed Applications and other settings like my $PATH, java, and .bash_profile. Will they be restored or survive the reinstall? Are those files and other hidden files backed up in time machine?

Comment: Yes. It should back up everything you need in order to restore your data and profile. Last time I did a reinstall and restore from Time Machine, it did retain my bash profile, and PATH data.

Comment: @DannyGibas Reinstalling and restoring from Time Machine isn't what's OP talking about. Read the question again: ...**without erasing the disk**.

Comment: Right! So what files/Applications where present BEFORE you restored from Time Machine?

Comment: @MiguelVelez "Reinstalling and restoring from Time Machine" (rather than restoring specific items from Time Machine) implies erasing the disk, so knowledge about that won't help you.

Comment: On a clean install, no user files will remain until restore from backup is done. The restore will automatically put the application files and supporting files back where they belong. On a "repair" is should ONLY impact system files, not user files - so that may be another option for you to try first as it is much faster. If that dont work to fix whatever issue you are having, then resort to the clean install.

Comment: "On a 'repair' is should ONLY impact system files, not user files - so that may be another option for you to try first as it is much faster." Oh god, the question was asking specifically about this all along (although it's off topic), so the OP doesn't need you for a pointer to that option. Next time, read the question before jumping to an answer.